# Is it possible to create Ubuntu Shirts ( Merchandise )

Tags: trademark

I wish to create a couple of Ubuntu shirts as prize for a coming event. In my country it is very difficult to get dollars($), Euros or any coin. This is the reason for making them here instead of buying them from the store. Will there be any problem in making them. Some of them will be similar to the ones in the ubuntu store but others will have other Ubuntu stuff.

Comment: http://shop.canonical.com/ accepts PayPal, which is also available in Venezuela. It will take about a week to transfer but there is your option. AFAIK making Ubuntu Branded T-Shirts **is** a nono.

Comment: Getting the $ here is the problem. And even if paypal shows Venezuela, with the limitation with have with $ it creates a sort of problem when using anything that uses dollars. If you can, search for "cadivi" which is the one that regulates the dollars here and asks too many questions for a ~400$ a year limit. Anyway thanks for the comment which I was also thinking but just in case I will wait for others to comment/answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible, so long as you follow the Trademark policy, the trademark page lists the policies (community advocacy probably applies to your activity).

http://www.ubuntu.com/aboutus/trademarkpolicy

Additional information is provided on the following links

http://design.ubuntu.com/assets/ubuntu-logo

Downloads - http://design.ubuntu.com/downloads?metadata=element-logo+brand-ubuntu

If you have questions, Contact Canonical Legal.

Comment: Well some shirts will have the Ubuntu logo. Others will have for example the "animal name" and the version of ubuntu starting from the beginning. Others will have all the animals randomly put in the shirt. For what I read this is possible from that trademark. Just in case they will not be sold but made and then offered as prize for people that can answer the most questions about ubuntu. I will however contact them for a permission and see how it goes. Wish me luck.

Comment: you likely wont have any issues as long as you are not making a profit from them or the event (yes even the event).

Comment: I am not sure they trademark the animals, just *ubuntu or *buntu and the actual logo on the page I added. Never hurts to ask Canonical. When you get an answer, please post back, I would be interested in follow up.